# Set default domain when using "Sign In With Google"

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, google-apps-for-education

Using the instructions for Google sign in located [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in), We are implementing the "Sign in with Google" button.

This implementation has been successful, however, we want to set a default domain other than gmail.com as this will be used by our Gsuite for education users. This would make it so that users can click the sign in button and just type their username, instead of username@gSuiteDomain.com

When this button is clicked:

[image: Log In With Google Button]

The user is redirected to:
[image]

**How do we make it so the second image defaults to our gSuite domain instead of gmail.com?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the simple directions at the location I linked in the question, as it is only for a basic minimum authentication.
For customization, you need to access the full client API [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) (server side validation can stay the same.)

This allows you to pass information to the init functions:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>
```

Then:

```
window.onLoadCallback = function () {
gapi.load('auth2', initSigninV2);

function initSigninV2() {
    gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'Your_client_id',
        hosted_domain: "YourHostedDomain.com"
    }).then(function (authInstance) {
        if (authInstance != null && authInstance != undefined) {
            gapi.signin2.render("IDOfSignInButton", { onsuccess: onSignIn });
        }
    });
}
```

The rest is the same as in the [original tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure is you set the ["hd" parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param) to the G Suite domain name that it will work.

Please let us know if that works.

Comment: That is the wrong answer, but it pointed me in the right direction. So I'll vote you up, but answer my own :) Thank you.

Comment: The HD parameter comes back within the ticket. So on the server you'd verify that the HD parameter contains your domain, to make sure that the account is an account that should be associated with your app.

Comment: This worked for me for a OAuth URL like `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=the_client_id&redirect_uri=the_redirect_url&response_type=code&scope=the_scope&state=the_state&hd=the_domain.com`

Thanks!